# VHDL : error in converting std_logic_vector to integer

Tags: vhdl

I was writing a code in vhdl (xilinx) for a digital tachometer.
While converting the `std_logic_vector` m1 to integer the following errors were shown by the compiler.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity tacho is
    Port ( A : in  STD_LOGIC;
           B : out  STD_LOGIC_vector (15 downto 0));
end tacho;

architecture Behavioral of tacho is
component counter
            port(
            clk: in std_logic;
            m: out std_logic_vector (4 downto 0));
end component;
signal m1 : std_logic_vector (4 downto 0); 
variable y: integer := 0;
variable z: integer := 0;           
begin
x: counter port map(A,m1);
y:= to_integer(unsigned(m1)); --error1:Syntax error near ":=". error2:Expecting type  void for <to_integer>.
z:= y * 60; --Syntax error near ":=".
B <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(z, 16));
end Behavioral;
```

I found in many websites that the syntax i wrote is correct.
Please help!

Comment: A tachometer usually counts the number of events over some sampling interval. That's not apparent in your design.

Comment: Don't use variables... well, at least: not like this. Also it is not advised to use unconstrained `integer`s in synthesis, as they will else expand to 32-bit values.

Answer (score 2):

Variables `y` and `z` can't be declared at architecture level. Use signals instead, and the signal assign `<=`, like:

```
...
  signal y : integer;
  signal z: integer := 0;           
begin
  x: counter port map(A, m1);
  y <= to_integer(unsigned(m1));
  z <= y * 60;
  B <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(z, 16));
...
```

Or simply combine it and avoid the intermediates `y` and `z`, like:

```
  ...
  x: counter port map(A, m1);
  B <= std_logic_vector(resize(60 * unsigned(m1), B'length));
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

A non-shared variable can only be declared in a process statement or subprogram. You could place your scaling code in a process:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity tacho is
    port ( A:   in  std_logic;
           B:   out std_logic_vector (15 downto 0)
    );
end entity tacho;

architecture behavioral of tacho is
    component counter is
        port (
            clk: in  std_logic;
            m:   out std_logic_vector (4 downto 0)
        );
    end component;
    signal m1 : std_logic_vector (4 downto 0);
begin

x: counter port map (A, m1);

scaling:
    process (m1)
        variable y: integer := 0;
        variable z: integer := 0;
    begin
        y := to_integer(unsigned(m1));
        z := y * 60;
        B <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(z, 16));
    end process;
end architecture behavioral;
```

Or you could move your calculations to a subprogram:

```
architecture scaled of tacho is
    component counter is
        port (
            clk: in  std_logic;
            m:   out std_logic_vector (4 downto 0)
        );
    end component;
    signal m1 : std_logic_vector (4 downto 0);
    function scale(m1: std_logic_vector (4 downto 0); SIZE: natural := 16)
            return std_logic_vector is
        variable y: integer;
        variable z: integer;
    begin
        y := to_integer(unsigned(m1));
        z := y * 60;
        return std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(z, SIZE));
    end function;
begin

x: counter port map (A, m1);
scaled_output:
    B <= scale(m1);
end architecture;
```

Both of these analyze.